# check.cpp file can not recognise enum TStatus, declared in check.h file

Tags: c++, class, enums

1. I declared enum file in check.h file as a public member of my class, but the problem was in check.cpp file I used a function TStatus check::getStatus() which has return type enum. It can not resolve the TStatus.
2. To solve the problem by declaring enum as a global variable, and in check.cpp and check.h files problems are solved.
3. Now I used a function which needs to check the return value form the TStatus check::getStatus() with the value from the enum.
4. This new function do not recognise the enum because it is not a member of the class.

My code is as follows. Please can anyone tell me is it possible to declare the enum as a class member, and can be recognised by the check.cpp file. Or there is another way to solve the problem.

**THIS IS CHECK.CPP FILE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "check.h"
using namespace std;


    check::check() { }

    TStatus check::getStatus()
    {
       return ok;
    }

    void check::print()
    {

        check object;

        if(object.getStatus() == TStatus::ok) cout<<"ok"<<endl;
        if(object.getStatus() == TStatus::sold) cout<<"sold"<<endl;
        if(object.getStatus() == defect) cout<<"defect"<<endl;

    }


    check::~check() { }
```

**THIS IS CHECK.H FILE**

```
#ifndef CHECK_H_
#define CHECK_H_

class check {
private:
    enum TStatus {  ok,sold,defect  };

public:

    check();
    ~check();
    TStatus getStatus();
    void print();

};

#endif /* CHECK_H_ */
```

Comment: You did not declare the enum in your class, why using `check::` to access them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your `enum TStatus` in the global scope. You cannot access it via `check::ok`. It would have to be declared in your class.

One way to access it is
`if (object.getStatus() == ok)`, the other
`if (object.getStatus() == TStatus::ok)` C++11 `enum class` would be required.

Better would be to move it inside your class, as `ok` could somewhere else be something different.

Comment: Thank you very much, when I put if (object.getStatus() == ok) it is not showing any error. 
But if I put if(object.getStatus() == TStatus::ok) it is showing this error. -->>‘TStatus’ is not a class or namespace

Comment: I waned to move it inside, but if I do that I get this error.. 

Multiple markers at this line
 - ‘TStatus’ does not name a type
 - Type 'TStatus' could not be resolved
 - Member declaration not found
 - No return, in function returning non-void

Comment: @rashedazad Could you update your question - below with the new class definition ?

Comment: @ Blacktempel   Hi, I update the question with enum as a private class member.  and the error is Multiple markers at this line
 - ‘TStatus’ does not name a type
 - Type 'TStatus' could not be resolved
 - Member declaration not found
 - No return, in function returning non-void

Comment: @rashedazad `check::TStatus check::getStatus()`